# Crystal Reports - Selecting data in the first row to be used in a formula

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I have a very basic report with no groups.  The details consists of a number of numeric columns.  I want to add a formula field which will use a field from the first row. Example:

(ColumnAFromCurrentRecord - ColumnBFromFirstRecord) / ColumnBFromFirstRecord

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to extact the column b from first record. try below solution.

```
Note: This is not a tested solution as I at present I don't have CR.
```

create below formula `Count` and place in detail section:

```
Local NumberVar a;
a:=a+1;
```

This will number the rows starting from **1** to the last row.

Now create one more formula `StoreB`:

```
Share NumberVar b;

if {@Count}=1
then b:=columnb
```

This will store the value of columnb in first record in variable b

Now use where you want:

```
EvaluateAfter(@StoreB)
Shared NumberVar b;

(ColumnAFromCurrentRecord - b) / b
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.  When I try saving the StoreB formula, it is telling me that a Boolean is expected at {@count}=1.

Comment: I think that's not the issue see my edited answer at that step

Comment: That helped and I got a little further, but it looks like the row count is not incrementing.  Every single row shows a 1 under the count column.

Comment: My mistake.  I had a typo that I didn't pick up on.  Everything works great now!  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1.
Create a formula named `AssignFirstValue` and define it like this:

```
WhilePrintingRecords; 
Global StringVar strFirstValue := {MYDBNAME.MYSTRINGFIELD};
```

Put the `AssignFirstValue` formula in your `Report Header` and suppress it.

2.
Create a formula named `PrintFirstValue` and define it like this:

```
WhilePrintingRecords; 
Global StringVar strFirstValue; 
strFirstValue
```

Put the `PrintFirstValue` formula wherever you want to display the first value in your report.