# compare the first row value for display in Crystal Report

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I need to show the text for comparing the first row specific field to each row for showing by using VS2015 for Crystal report. I searched and found the similar answer. [Crystal Reports - Selecting data in the first row to be used in a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573250/crystal-reports-selecting-data-in-the-first-row-to-be-used-in-a-formula). However, I get the error  " The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula" when I did the second formula. Would some one show me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

I  followed the website to create @Count

```
Local NumberVar a;
a:=a+1;
```

Then I create the next formula:

```
Share DateTimeVar b;
if {@Count}=1 then
    b:={Report_Sub;1.START_TIME}
```

Comment: it is not `Share` it is `Shared`

Answer (score 0):

this must be:

```
 b:={Report_Sub}
```

or

```
b:={1.START_TIME}
```